# Joomla 3 and Image gallery - sigplus

Tags: joomla3.0

My page is http://www.budrysl2.ayz.pl/portal_new/praca-szkoly/wydarzenia/komunikaty/aktualnosci-uczniowskie

I try to use sig but I doesn't work.
In my article there is code {gallery}2016-17/pr_pow_ch{/gallery} but to gallery is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the requirements for this plugin to work.

1. Whether the Content - Image gallery - sigplus plugin is enabled.
2. Check if the folder name and path is correct.